# Date Format in CiviEvent Widget is not in German Format

Tags: civievent, widget

The date format in the CiviCrm event list widget switch not to german format. I administer all known format settings to the german settings. But only in the event list widget it shows no effect. 
Is there an option that I not found?
I use wordpress 4.9.1 with Tortuga and CiviCrm 4.7.27

Comment: Hej Grischan, did you managed this issue? Maybe you like to share your solution? I have the same problem here. Best

Comment: @wintermoor i changed your ANswer to a comment. perhaps you do not yet have 'reputation' to add comments. but we can't leave an 'i have this problem too' as an answer. sorry. but it would just get down marks.

Answer (score 2):

Set default via Administer -> Localisation -> Date Formats
Date Format: Time Only
%H:%M

Events use the activityDateTime, which can be adjusted here:
Administer -> Customise Data and Screens -> Date Preferences

This will change event descriptions, confirmation mails and such. If you use a CiviEvent calendar, it's view is not corrected though.

Answer (score 0):

Go to /wp-content/plugins/civievent-widget and edit following values written in 'single quotation marks' in civievent-widget.php:

- Change date from '%b %E, %Y' to '%d.%m.%Y' in line 192 (date).
- Change time frome '%l:%M %p' to '%H:%M' in line 196.
- You may like to change the title 'Upcoming Events' in line 173, too.

Please note that the next update of this plugin will override these settings.